# Strip characters from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, discord.py, bots

I have a discord bot running on a python script, and its token is stored in a `.txt` file. If I read from the file using:

```
with open('Stored Discord Token.txt') as storedToken:
    TOKEN = storedToken.readlines()
```

I can get the discord bot token. The problem is that the discord bot token looks like this:

`[' <token> ']`

This causes an error when trying to run the script, and the bot fails to connect, as it is an invalid token:

```
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

How do I remove the square brackets, `'`s and spaces from the list containing the token?

---

**TL;DR**: How to remove `[`, `]`, `'`, and `spaces` from a single item list?

Comment: If you're absolutely certain that the token string has that form, why not just slice out the appropriate substring?

Comment: @Brian it turns out that my answer to my question is to simply do `string[-1]` which removed the unwanted characters... I discovered that by accident...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `read()` will just return the whole file contents as a string, so you could use `TOKEN = storedToken.read()`.

Lists in Python can be accessed using `[index]` so to access the first line in the file you can do `TOKEN = storedToken.readlines()[0]`. If say you wanted to access the `n`th line you could do `storedToken.readlines()[n]`. Where `n` is an `int`.

Comment: Turns out I made this more complicated that It should have been... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Brian suggested, slicing out the substring solves the problem. If we simply add one line of code, like this:

```
with open('Stored Discord Token.txt') as file:
    fileContents = file.readlines()
    TOKEN = fileContents[-1]
```

we remove the `[`, `]`, `'`, and   characters, and can now successfully pass that string as the token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import re
a=[' <token123> ']
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', str(a))
```